# How to setup Postgres as Database for Hyperledger Aries DotNet Mediator

Tags: .net, aries, hyperledger-indy

Im using Hyperledger.Aries.Routing.Mediator in Nuget Version 1.5.5 and want to use the Hyperledger Indy-Postgres Plugin instead of the default SQLlite.
I think that i somewhere must define in my code something like

```
options.WalletConfiguration.StorageType = "postgres_storage";
```

together with some WalletStorageConfigurations and StorageCredentials;

On start of my mediator i get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception. Hyperledger.Indy.WalletApi.UnknownWalletTypeException: The wallet type specified has not been registered.
```

=> Questions:

- must i do some init elsewhere?
- what have i to do to install the postgres-plugin itself?
- is the any documentation out there beneat the indy-sdk - docs?